# SQL server constraint - unique key or index?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains all products. There are 3 distinct types of products so these have their own tables, lets say `ProductType1, ProductType2, ProductType3`.

There is a 1-1 relationship between `Products` and `ProductType(n)` on `ProductId`, but to further constraint the child tables there is an additional relationship using a `ProductId, ProductTypeId` in `Products`, and a `ProductId, ComputedProductTypeId` in each of the other tables.

This ensures that a product can only be added to a single matching `ProductType` table.

The question is this. As there is already a relationship between the 2 tables on `ProductId`, rather than using an index for the FK, can I get away with a unique key to constrain the relationship, or will this cause performance issues?

**Products**

```
PK ProductId
FK ProductId, ProductTypeId
 ^
*Add an index for this or unique key constraint?*
```

**ProductType(n)**

```
PK ProductId
FK ProductID, ComputedProductTypeId (fixed int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an index will be better approach.
If you want to delete entries from your master table, SQL server looks for FK relations if any exists. So Creating Index on your composite key (which includes FK) will speed up the process.